# How can I delete records from two tables that share related information?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make ONE delete query that will delete data from the following two database tables.

```
**User_List**
- id
- user_id
- name

**User_Items**
- id
- user_list_id
- item name
```

What I want to happen is... First it finds all of the User_List records that have a user_id value of 1. Then it deletes all of the User_Items that have a user_list_id that matches the id of the results from the previous statement. Then once all User_Items matching the criteria has been deleted, I want to delete all of the User_List elements as well.

I'm sure there is a way to do all this with one query, but I don't know how?

Comment: Do you have a foreign key? could add a delete cascade. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: No I don't have a foreign key.

Comment: To elaborate, *this is functionality that RDBMS systems like MySQL are **designed to perform for you***.  Define your foreign key relationships properly and whenever you delete a record from `User_List`, all its associated records in `User_Items` will also be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
 DELETE ul, ui
 FROM User_List ul
 LEFT JOIN User_Items ui ON ul.user_id = ui.user_list_id
 WHERE ul.user_id = 1
```

Comment: This works, but if User_List does not have any User_Items then the User_List record is not deleted... I need it to be deleted even if no User_Items exist for it.

Comment: So maybe try a left join?